# Error in C / arduino on pointer conversion

Tags: c, pointers, arduino

I have the following function **blinkLed**

```
uint8_t status_led_pin = 4;  

unsigned long long *previous_blink = 0;       
uint8_t *led_state = 0;  

void setup() {
 pinMode (status_led_pin, OUTPUT);
 digitalWrite(status_led_pin,0);
}

void loop() {
  while(millis() <= 10000){
    blinkLed(status_led_pin,&led_state,1000,&previous_blink);  
  }
  digitalWrite(status_led_pin,0);

}


void blinkLed(uint8_t led, uint8_t *led_state, unsigned long long interval, unsigned long long *last_blink_millis){
   unsigned long long now = millis();

   if((now - *last_blink_mills) >= interval){
      *last_blink_millis = now;
      *led_state = !*led_state;

      digitalWrite(led,*led_state);
   }
}
```

And the error fired when I call the **digitalWrite** function:

> cannot convert 'uint8_t** {aka unsigned char**}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' for argument '2' to 'void blinkLed(uint8_t, uint8_t*, long long unsigned int, long long unsigned int*)'

Any idea?

Comment: `char` I don't understand, but `last_blink_mills` is a pointer so `now - last_blink_mills` is invalid. Should be `now - *last_blink_mills` and `*last_blink_millis = now;`

Comment: Please show the prototype of `digitalWrite`

Comment: The documentation says that the function expects two characters. The compiler tells you that you are passing a pointer where it expects a character. It can't really be any more explicit than that.

Comment: Ludin I understand that, but how to I solve it? I can't pass &led_state

Answer (score 2):

You ignore that you are working with pointers. Also, from the error message it seems the prototype of `digitalWrite` is:

```
void digitalWrite(char, char);
```

so the code should be:

```
void blinkLed(uint8_t led, uint8_t *led_state, int interval, unsigned long long *last_blink_millis){
   unsigned long long now = millis();


   if((int)(now - *last_blink_mills) >= interval){
      *last_blink_millis = now;
      *led_state = !*led_state;

      digitalWrite(led,*led_state);
   }
}
```

Comment: I call the function blinkLed like this:
  blinkLed(status_led_pin,&led_state,1000,&previous_blink);
If I modify as you said I will get the same error, but this time as double pointer

Comment: @GeorgianStan - No.  `*` is the inverse of `&`.  The type of the *expression* `*led_state` is `uint8_t`, not `uint8_t **`

Comment: And how should I call this function then?

Answer (score 1):

Change the declarations

```
unsigned long long *previous_blink = 0;       
uint8_t *led_state = 0;
```

to

```
unsigned long long previous_blink = 0;
uint8_t led_state = 0;
```

You want `previous_blink` and `led_state` to store *values* of type `unsigned long long` and `uint8_t`.  When you pass them to `blinkled` from `loop`, you want `blinkled` to *update* those objects, so you have to pass pointers to those objects.

Remember that C passes all function parameters *by value*, meaning that the formal parameter in the function definition is a separate object in memory from the actual parameter in the function call. So to update a parameter, we must pass a pointer:

```
void update( T *ptr ) // for any type T 
{
  *ptr = new_value(); // write a new value to the thing ptr points to
}

void call( void )
{
  T val;             // val is an object of type T
  update( &val );    // pass a pointer to val to update
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`digitalWrite()` takes `value` by value, not by pointer, so it should be

```
 digitalWrite(led,*led_state);
```

you forgot dereferences everywhere in code. Line

```
 led_state = !led_state;
```

doesn't produce error because it's legal, but it's a huge bug. After this pointer `led_state` is a null pointer if it wasn't null. I'm sure you meant

```
 *led_state = !(*led_state);
```

Also it's unclear what you expect, because nothing in documentation allows to supply arbitrary values to `digitalWrite`, only HIGH and LOW. Not sure what they are equal to, if LOW is 0, then you're fine, otherwise line above result in zero written to `led_state`
Common style documentation offers is:

```
 if(*led_state)
      digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
 else
      digitalWrite(led,LOW);
```

Comment: Not working:
I am calling the function like this:
  blinkLed(status_led_pin,&led_state,1000,&previous_blink);
If I modify as you said I get the same error but as double pointer:

cannot convert 'uint8_t** {aka unsigned char**}' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' for argument '2' to 'void blinkLed(uint8_t, uint8_t*, int, long long unsigned int*)'
When I call the function

Comment: You are reporting an error in the _call_ of `blinkLed`, not in the _code_ of `blinkLed`.

Comment: Yes, but after I did the changes